# Flexbox align-self being ignored

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The documentation for [`align-self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) states:

> The align-self CSS property aligns flex items of the current flex line overriding the align-items value.

However, this does not happen:

```css
.example {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 8ex;
}

.example > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#a > div:last-child {
  align-self: top;
}

#b > div:last-child {
  align-self: center;
}

#c > div:last-child {
  align-self: bottom;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="a" class="example"><div>1</div><div>2</div></div>
<div id="b" class="example"><div>1</div><div>2</div></div>
<div id="c" class="example"><div>1</div><div>2</div></div>
</body>
```

The docs also say:

> If any of the item's cross-axis margin is set to auto, then align-self is ignored. The property doesn't apply to block-level boxes, or to table cells.

However, none of these things work:

- Explicitly adding `margin:0` to the child `div`s.
- Adding `display:inline` to the child `div`s.
- Changing the `div`s to `span`s.

Why is `align-self` not working?

Comment: [meta-tag:feature-request]: Ability to downvote your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`top` and `bottom` are not valid values for `align-self`. Use `flex-start` and `flex-end` instead:

```css
.example {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 8ex;
}

.example > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#a > div:last-child {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

#b > div:last-child {
  align-self: center;
}

#c > div:last-child {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="a" class="example"><div>1</div><div>2</div></div>
<div id="b" class="example"><div>1</div><div>2</div></div>
<div id="c" class="example"><div>1</div><div>2</div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I guess I was so hyperfocused on `align-items` and that opening paragraph that I somehow didn't register that the options weren't valid. Now I kind of want to downvote my own question. Awesome, thanks!